# Ajax Model Popup Extender

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Public Property Drag As Boolean' is obsolete: 'The drag feature on modal popup will be automatically turned on if you specify the PopupDragHandleControlID property. Setting the Drag property is a noop'.

While compiling the .Net(4.0) code it shows the warning. How we will remove or clear the warning.

Please guide me

Comment: can you add your code of the model pop up extender?

Comment: What the problem to specify `PopupDragHandleControlID` property with the same ID that used for `PopupControlID` property?

Comment: i have removed the "Drag" property, but the popup has been draggable. I am expecting the popup should not draggable at the time warning also should not come.

Comment: Here my code: I need to remove my warning                                       <AjaxControlToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="xxx" runat="server" Drag="true" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
                                        PopupControlID="xxx" TargetControlID="btnCancel">
 </AjaxControlToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>

Answer (score 0):

means that ModalPopupExtender.Drag will no longer supported in .Net framework, so instead of that you can use PopupDragHandleControlID property.

dont use Drag , use PopupDragHandleControlID